# Show Profile Picture without Login

Tags: android, facebook, button, authentication

I am trying to show a Facebook Profile Picture without implementing the Facebook Login Button. I am  using the Facebook SDK.

Currently my profile picture looks like this:

[image]

I successfully connected to Facebook and used the `com.facebook.widget.ProfilePictureView` to display an empty profile picture in the `xml`

Now I am having trouble in my java class trying to retrieve my profile picture:

Game.java

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    ...
    ...

    // Find the user's profile picture custom view
    profilePictureView = (ProfilePictureView) findViewById(R.id.selection_profile_pic);
    profilePictureView.setCropped(true);

    // view that in turn displays the profile picture.
    profilePictureView.setProfileId(GraphUser.getId()); //eror

    ...
    ...
}
```

The error is with this line: `profilePictureView.setProfileId(GraphUser.getId())`

In the tutorial they show the profile picture like this:

```
        @Override
        public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
            // If the response is successful
            if (session == Session.getActiveSession()) {
                if (user != null) {
                    // Set the id for the ProfilePictureView
                    // view that in turn displays the profile picture.
                    profilePictureView.setProfileId(user.getId());
                    // Set the Textview's text to the user's name.
                    userNameView.setText(user.getFirstName());
                }
            }
            if (response.getError() != null) {
                // Handle errors, will do so later.
            }
        }
```

But in my case I don't have a login session and just want to load a quick profile photo. So I tried simply substituting `profilePictureView.setProfileId(user.getId());` for `profilePictureView.setProfileId(GraphUser.getId());` since `user` is of type `GraphUser`

Compilation Error: When I write `profilePictureView.setProfileId(GraphUser.getId());` it says Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getId() from the type GraphUser

Can someone please help me load my profile photo? Is this possible without implementing Facebook Login first?

Comment: What is the error? Could you give us the stacktrace or more information on what causes the problem? Also did you set an errorListener on your profilePictureView? `setOnErrorListener(OnErrorListener)`

Comment: vincent i edited the post above with the error

Comment: I think @luschn answer is right. You can access the pictures without login if the user authorized it by just setting the user id in the profilePictureView but if you don't have the user id, you have absolutely no way to create it :)

Comment: see my answer. of course there´s an error, without user authorizaion there is no getId. I am not an Android expert, but i assume you would have to use an instance of GraphUser to be able to use getId - of course after authorization. which is exactly what the error message tells you. getId is not a static function.

Comment: yes, and you ONLY get the user id with authorization. my answer is 100% correct :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without authorizing a User, the User is completely anonymous. So the answer is no, you can´t show anything without login, and you certainly can´t get the User ID without login (which is what you would need to get the profile picture). The User ID would even give you access to the real name of every User. Of course that´s not possible without authorization.

More information about Login (on Android): https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/login-with-facebook/v2.2

Comment: thank you luschn for this answer. I was hoping for a little work-around this problem.